# Como criar um campo dinamicamente no Ionic e/ou AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Tenha uma lista de produtos, mas minha lista não tem o campo quantidade, e nem deve ter porque seria controle de estoque e não é isso.

Quero o campo quantidade para quando clicar em (+) acrescentar 1 e clicar em (-) diminuir 1.

Tento criar o campo quantidade no controller desta forma:

```
$scope.user.bebidasextras.quantidade=0;
```

E no View desta forma:

```
<i class='icon ion-plus-round icon-plus-round' mouse-down-up ng-click='addProduct(product)'></i>
                             <span class='product-quantity'>{{bebida.quantidade}}</span>
<i class='icon ion-minus-round icon-minus-round' mouse-down-up ng-click='removeProduct(product)'></i>
```

Mas nem o valor zero (0) não aparece em minha view para que o usuário entenda que o item está zerado.

Como criar este campo, que será salvo depois?

Comment: Preciso ver mais parte do código para poder ajudar. No scope vc sempre tem 1 produto só ou é um array? Na view essa parte do código está dentro de um ng-repeat?

Comment: No seu scope vc colocou `$scope.user.bebidasextras.quantidade` e na sua view vc deve colocar `{{user.bebidasextras.quantidade}}`.